# Does my deploy user need to belong to the sudoer list for Upstart to start GUnicorn?

Tags: upstart, sudo, gunicorn

Does my deploy user need to belong to the sudoer list for Upstart to start GUnicorn?

Here is the error from my Upstart log

> deploy is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

It works fine if I do not specify the setuid and setgid. But I suspect that running the process as root is not a good idea. This is the upstart script that I'm running:

> description "Gunicorn for django_instance"
>
> start on (filesystem) stop on runlevel [016]
>
> respawn console log
>
> # Setting these to nobody and nogroup does not work either
>   # setuid nobody
>   # setgid nogroup
>
> setuid deploy
>
> setgid deploy
>
> script
>
> ```
> chdir /home/deploy/django_instance
> exec sudo -u deploy -g deploy /home/deploy/venvs/test_env/bin/gunicorn django_instance.wsgi:application
> ```
>
> end script

Comment: The upstart version I'm using is the one which comes default with Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS